# How to build a CSS style with a LESS mixin parameter?

Tags: css, less

Due to [CSS specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/) issues, I am attempting to build a CSS expression with a LESS mixin as follows:

```
// overriding any previous styling with a more specific expression:
.styleSpecificListElement(@id: "#index") {
    main .list ul @{id} a {
        // referencing another mixin here:
        .setLiStyling();
    }
}
```

LESS *will* parse this, however it is parsed with the inserted parameter in double-quotes, in which does not evaluate as intended:

```
/* don't want the double-quotes around the id: */
main .list ul "#index" a {
    /* ...code from the .setLiStyling() mixin generated here... */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok nevermind, I just figured it out -- the hash-symbol `#` can precede the `@{id}` reference in the mixin, where the parameter is then passed as a String *without* quotes:

```
.styleSpecificListElement(@id: index) {
    main .list ul #@{id} a {
        // referencing another mixin here:
        .setLiStyling();
    }
}
```

...where calling `.styleSpecificListElement(foobar)` will then parse into CSS as:

```
main .list ul #foobar a {
    /* ...code from the .setLiStyling() mixin generated here... */
}
```

Comment: You also can use escaped value: `.styleSpecificListElement(~'#foobar');`

Comment: @seven-phases-max -- Interesting, thanks! Your solution is closer to being "semantically correct" than mine I think, however it would be ideal to just pass `"#foobar"` *without* the `~`.